# Are there any alternatives to tomb?

Tags: gratis, linux, open-source, encryption

I mean this [tomb](https://www.dyne.org/software/tomb/). My web browser throws a warning for their security certificate (unknown issuer) and judging by their github page, it's not developed too actively.

Are there any alternatives that work exactly the same way: by storing a whole LUKS encrypted filesystem inside a single file? The filesystem inside the container file should be able to be mounted transparently, just like a regular LUKS filesystem on a real partition (tomb can do this).

This rules out [ecryptfs](http://ecryptfs.org/) as option, because it encrypts every file on its own.

I also want to avoid truecrypt/veracrypt due to past controversies related to this project (they were the reason why I looked for an alternative to them when I found tomb).

Also, since LUKS is Linux specific and only works on just 1-2 BSD flavors as I know, any solution that works for both Linux and BSD flavors (at least OpenBSD, NetBSD and FreeBSD) is very welcome. I just emphasize again that the main requirement is to be able to store a whole encrypted filesystem inside a single file.

---

Comment: @Izzy I have added the detail you're mentioning too. One uses a LUKS encrypted filesystem by mounting it then copying data into, regardless of it living inside a single container file or on a real partition. I don't think it's possible to use it as an archive by producing it directly from regular files.

Comment: Thanks, now it should be complete – upvoted :)